# how to use uwsgi restart django

Tags: django, uwsgi, restart

I have a `wsgi.ini` file in my project, and I use `uwsgi wsgi.ini` to run my project.But when I change the django code,I want to restart the project instead kill uwsgi then reload it. The uwsgi official document provide the following methods:

    `` # using kill to send the signal
    kill -HUP `cat /tmp/project-master.pid`
    # or the convenience option --reload
    uwsgi --reload /tmp/project-master.pid
    # or if uwsgi was started with touch-reload=/tmp/somefile
    touch /tmp/somefile ``

But I don't have a `project-master.pid` file in `/tmp` catalog in my system(centOS).

## my question:

1. how to use uwsgi restart django instead of kill it then start it?
2. if use uwsgi official document provided method,how to create a `.pid` file and what content should in this file?

Comment: You should show how you are starting uWSGI in the first place.

Comment: wsgi.ini file is in my project,and I start django use this command: uwsgi wsgi.ini

Comment: this is my `uwsgi.ini` file:
    [uwsgi]
    socket = 127.0.0.1:8833
    chdir = /home/wangcai/server/international_lottery
    module = international_lottery.wsgi
    master = True
    processes = 4
    vacuum = True
    buffer-size = 32768
    daemonize = /home/wangcai/log/uwsgi.log

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I find the anwser. `project-master.pid` is set in `wsgi.ini` file, you should set `pidfile=/tmp/project-master.pid` first. Then use uwsgi to start server: `uwsgi wsgi.ini`.After you start it, you can see a `project-master.pid` file in `/tmp` catalog. When you want to reload uwsgi server, you can use such command to restart server:  `uwsgi --reload /tmp/project-master.pid`.

Comment: Although this is not required for development purposes, for production this is helpful.

Answer (score 6):

I found simplier answer in my opinion, you can just kill your uwsgi process and then spawn it again:

```
killall uwsgi
```

And then just run your uwsgi command again.

Comment: I used this command but my website is still running. How can I know if uwsgi has stopped?

Comment: Typically, a kill signal should be enough, a new uwsgi process should re-spawn automatically.

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to use uWSGI server for your local development needs. Apache/uWSGI are meant for production, and having them restarted implicitly at every code change is not often desirable. In fact, production server not restarting even after the code is changed often acts as a safety net, so that you don't end up restarting the server without finalising the deployment.

Just use inbuild server django provides with itself.

```
python manage.py runserver 8000
```

Comment: In fact, I use uWSGI in production environment, if I kill server and then start it may be affect some users. So I want a method to restart server and don't affect users.

Comment: @Cherry restart gracefully such that ongoing requests are handled first.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have fond the anwser today.