Django compilemessages does not apply changes in production
i am currently developing a web application using django + postgres + nginx + docker, everything runs already. I now developed a feature where you can change the translation file (.po) while logged in as admin. It works on my development environment and also when printing out the commandlines it seems, that the application applies the changes inside the docker image. but when i use call_command("compilemessages) it does not apply the changes. The .po file was updated but not the entry on the website itself.
So the logic works but i want the changes to be set permanently when changed. Is this a Nginx caching problem or am i oversseing something important?
these are my files:
docker-compose.prod.yml:
services:
  web:
    build: ./app
    command: bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && gunicorn --timeout 120 wtc_research.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000"
    # command: bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && waitress-serve --listen=*:8000 wtc_research.wsgi:application"
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/staticfiles/
      - locale_volume:/locale/
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    expose:
      - "8000"
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:16
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
      - ./django_dump.sql:/home/django_dump.sql
      - ./translated_text.sql:/home/translated_text.sql
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod.db
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/staticfiles/
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - web
volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_volume:
  locale_volume:


I am not sure what to do, also browsing through django docs i cant anything related to this. Does someone has an idea. The goal is a POFIleEditor mask in my webapplication.
Thanks in advance!
The logic works, since on my local development there are no errors also in the container i can see that it also works but it just wont displayed on my website. Also changes stay in the container and the file wont get updated in my repository. This could be solved by mounting the volume but i cant get a solution for the live translation changes.

It seems like the translation information is in memory and needs to be reloaded after you recompiled it. I found this thread from 2007 but they don't seem to have a solution. https://groups.google.com/g/django-users/c/4uvY5YrDaKc?pli=1
Maybe this hint helps you anyways.

If you use uwsgi, this could also help you reload the server code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46172595/how-to-use-uwsgi-restart-django

Maybe you need to restart the WSGI server to reload the content, on dev env this may be done automatically as the Django Server restarts with files change through watches
